# Oracle not available in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, odp.net

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on a machine which already had Oracle data provider for .net (odp.net) and I wanted to use Entity Framework with Oracle but Oracle connection is not available:

[image]

The odp.net was working with Visual Studio 2013 Professional before I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio to use any of the database related designers in Visual Studio:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html